# Dynamic Image Button not Resizing

Tags: android, imagebutton

Here is an arraylist of my button being generated in my LinearLayout, the thing is, I already indicated the size in 24x24, but when I emulate it, it does not resize at all. Please help me, I would greatly Appreciate it :D

```
 public void generate_btnRemoveContact()
    {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lytContactParams=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(24,24);
        lytContactParams.weight=.5f;
        btnRemoveContact.add(new ImageButton(getApplicationContext()));
        btnRemoveContact.get(cntContact);
        btnRemoveContact.get(cntContact).setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        btnRemoveContact.get(cntContact).setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_remove_circle_outline_red_24dp);
        btnRemoveContact.get(cntContact).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        btnRemoveContact.get(cntContact).setTag(cntContact);
        btnRemoveContact.get(cntContact).setId(cntContact);

        btnRemoveContact.get(cntContact).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for (int rmvCnt = v.getId(); rmvCnt < cntContact; rmvCnt++) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "you selected " + rmvCnt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });'



        lytContact.addView(btnRemoveContact.get(cntContact));

        cntContact++;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code you posted, you need to set the LayoutParams on the ImageButton:

```
btnRemoveContact.get(cntContact).setLayoutParams(lytContactParams);
```